# autoincrement primary key in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

this is my code in my mysql query

```
require("lib/dbfunctions.inc.php");

    $qry = "select max(role_id) as nextrnum from Role";

    $nextrnum = execute_query($qry);

    $line = get_row($nextrnum);

    $nextRoleNum = "R" . str_pad((trim(substr($line['nextrnum'],1))+1),2,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

i have insert some data in my database which looks like this

```
INSERT INTO Role VALUES
 ('R0','IT'),
('R1','Staff'),
('R2','Administrator');
```

but when i click the add form link i got an error.r

```
ERROR: Record could not be added
Duplicate entry 'R0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

not sure why i got this error

Comment: how about using int for ids and mysql-bulit-in auto-increment?

Comment: Given it's a role number, why not simply store it as an integer (0, 1, ...) instead of R0, R1, etc.? If you do that, you just have to set your primary key to auto-increment and you're done.

Comment: when i select * from my tables,Yes R0 was there..when i click on add Form my new id was R03, it should be R3..mi sure my code reads R0 from R03..im not sure why i got this error

Comment: is there is an error along this code?..$nextRoleNum = "R" . str_pad((trim(substr($line['nextrnum'],1))+1),2,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A primary key should be an INT, not VARCHAR.
2. Auto increment means that you don't specify the ID's yourself (thus, auto), and it is an inherent feature of MYSQL, which you should utilize when creating the table structure.

You get the duplicate error because you ran the insert query more than once, thus trying to enter a duplicate ID, which is forbidden by the nature of a PRIMARY KEY - that is a **unique** identifier.

Instead you just leave the value NULL and MYSQL takes care of it (provided that you set the ID field as auto-increment):

```
INSERT INTO Role VALUES
(NULL,'IT'),
(NULL,'Staff'),
(NULL,'Administrator');
```

Otherwise, you may use the alternative INSERT syntax, where you specify only the columns you need to insert manually:

```
INSERT INTO Role 
(column1,column2,column3) // id column won't be included
VALUES 
(value1,value2,value3)
```